# Within C# properties I am doing encryption and decryption within try/catch. What could be the alternate

Tags: c#

I have odata web api endpoints. on `Post` I want to store the encrypted value into database for `Name`, but on `Get` I want to show decrypted value. I am using `DPAPI` with `CurrentUser` scope.

In C# class I am using below code for `Name` property like below,

```cs
public string Name
{
    get => _name;
    set
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

        _name = DOIt(value);
    }
}

private string DOIt(string value)
{
    try
    {
        return value.DecryptData();
    }
    catch
    {
        return value.EncryptData();
    }
}
```

In `try` block first I am checking if I can decrypt the string, else in `catch` I am encrypt it.

Things is working as per expectation, on `Post` value is encrypted and store into table column and on `Get`, I am getting decrypted value.

Is this any other alternate? Thanks!

Comment: why `close` vote dude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, a "flip-flop" API like that sounds kind of terrible.

How about just making it clear that the backing field is always encrypted?

```
public string Name
{
    get => _encryptedName.DecryptData();
    set {
        _encryptedName = value.EncryptData();
    }
}
```

(As an aside, I assume `EncryptData` and `DecryptData` are your personal extension methods – it doesn't quite sound very secure that you can just encrypt and decrypt things without any keys or anything...)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but it's store un-ecrypted value in database on Post.

Comment: There is no database. Nobody can find issues in code that is not here.